# Which event should we subscribe to if we want code to be triggered when a new user registers?

Tags: 8, event-subscribers

I noticed that *account.set* is the event invoked for a user account.

I want to create an event subscriber which adds a callback invoked when a new user registers on the site. I am not sure whether *account.set* is the correct event.

Are there other better events for this?

Comment: I'll try to put a proper answer in later when I have time (if no one else has already done it), but have a read through https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2551893 for further info. Bottom line is entity CRUD still uses hooks, unless you use one of the contrib modules that add events for them

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`AccountEvents::SET_USER`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Session%21AccountEvents.php/constant/AccountEvents%3A%3ASET_USER/8.8.x) isn't the event for user registration. Per the docs:

> This event allows modules to perform an action whenever the current user is
>   set. The event listener receives an \Drupal\Core\Session\AccountSetEvent
>   instance.

The event is fired when Drupal initializes the user object for the current request, not when new users are created.

For responding to new user creation, you can still use [`hook_user_insert()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_insert/8.8.x).

Comment: Aww. I was hoping to write an event subscriber and use Drupal 8's new methods to get the job done. What a pity ;-)

Answer (score 3):

> Aww. I was hoping to write an event subscriber and use Drupal 8's new
>   methods to get the job done. What a pity ;-)

**You could using the [Hook Event Dispatcher](https://www.drupal.org/project/hook_event_dispatcher) module**, see [README.md](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/hook_event_dispatcher/-/blob/8.x-1.x/README.md) file on how to use.

> [image]
>
> This module dispatches events for several Drupal core hooks. This
>   allows you to use the D8 Event Subscriber system, instead of the
>   outdated hook system, to react on certain events.